# How to catch JasperException with web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, exception, web.xml

I've got the following lines in my web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/mobile/errors/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/mobile/errors/undefined.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/mobile/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<!-- org.apache.jasper.JasperException -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/jsp/mobile/errors/undefined.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.apache.jasper.JasperException</exception-type>
    <location>/jsp/mobile/errors/undefined.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The web application successfully caught a HTTP 404 error and redirected to the specified error page but nothing else.
For example, I provoked my web app by not closing a jstl c:if tag.
I can see a JasperException thrown in my console.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/mobile/main.jsp(291,2) Unterminated &lt;c:if tag
```

But I see an empty page without any html in it. I don't see the 500.jsp page or undefiend.jsp either.

What am I doing wrong ? 

**EDIT 1**
I'm not sure it's relevant but I'm using Spring MVC.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>shop</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>shop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.spr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Handle jsp error by setting `errorPage` declaration

Comment: In each existing jsp file ? I could do that but to me that smells bad.

Comment: What is the url of the empty page ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot The URL is the error-throwing page's URL localhost:8081/shop/

Comment: I'm not sure if its the problem but do you have `isErrorPage=true` for `undefined.jsp` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've also got exception.printStackTrace() added